# NumberExpresion in QueryDSL

Tags: java, querydsl

how can I get the `Integer` value of a `NumberExpresion` object? `intValue()` function just returns another instance of `NumberExpresion` object.

Comment: It's for query building. It's used when evaluating conditions. Why do you want to get the value? For query chaining?

Comment: No, for test case assertion, for example counting rows of a table.

Comment: It's unclear what you're going to do. Since expression is just expression, you cannot get value from it without input. Can you post your revelant code here?